# Kidnapped Chapter 1: Marcus’ message

Tags: story

You and your friend Marcus celebrated his birthday at your house, but when you wake up, you find an audio recorder with a white label on it, saying: “sorry buddy”. You play the recorder and practise your scales and pieces of music. Then you put down the instrument and press play on the audio recorder. You make out the words:

“Easily the hardest part of recording this is that I... uhh just y’know, am... erm sorry for what I am doing to ya. Cuts me deep to say this, but I held... *sigh* this secret close to me. Hard to understand, it is, but I am at... odds with the fact that you trusted me. I’m not the person you thought I was. I might sound a bit jittery but that’s just me, noooooothing else, no deeper meaning or anything. Of course you’re smart, so I know you’ll get this. Involving this, the... ummm question if we should stay united... uhh and, the United Kingdom.. errr I will head... erm away. Next to my friendship with you there is a quarter... umm of me that you can’t see. Centrally, I’m sorry, and goodbye and good luck.”

You sit back, and try to process what happened. This isn’t like Marcus, and the way he was saying it was extremely odd. After an hour of studying this, you find out where he is, and the name of what could’ve taken him.

Comment: Hey guys, this is my first riddle like this, so please don’t get angry at me if it isn’t good, and: enjoy!

Comment: Typo/autocorrect in the last sentence? "After hour she of studying this"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hidden message is:

> I am held at the united Kingdom head quarter
>  
>
>  You get it by taking every word before he pauses speaking.

He probably got caught by:

> Secret Intelligence Service

Comment: I'd say Marcus is really clear-headed for someone who just got kidnapped :)

Comment: @V.Courtois And the one who caught him isn´t the smartest :D

Comment: Good answer, but there IS a way to find out who kidnapped him. UK HQ of what? Well done though

Comment: @V.Courtois Maybe this wasn’t AFTER he was captured

Comment: @Rohit Jose I figured this out too, in fact the fact that the record was there was surprising too. I wanna read chapter 2 :)

Comment: It’s coming soon