# Kidnapped Chapter 2: Password Please

Tags: story

Continued from Kidnapped Chapter 1:
(You need to have solved the [previous riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70246/kidnapped-chapter-1-marcus-message) to solve this)

You find out who took Marcus, and where, and you get ready to go get him, but you accidentally press rewind, and before you could stop it, you find a hidden backwards message saying: “Use their name, you need the password”, then a list of gibberish:

xjl difuaqyr qf ylca gmpvst vt mpjs avi’zr kr cur gbwv pham vp fkuozl. wwg avm cwfnpq kbpxcpburpx ulqbbt epk hpnv qcpb kucvcjhme imts tzbo xjl tqeux kszczkrcl tqyg xjpbo, nnp ku zwjgvehgm. gjitl wa aq xkts, q uczg ac trczg avqf cw xhucr cw rvgavdpg, iib lqy ehb lb vlkz, mwh’xi ivhbrp xjpg nnt.

What’s the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a Vigenere cipher with keyword

> ECHO INC.

The decoded message is:

> the password is what sector of echo you’re in and your name in binary. use the public containment sector and that main character girl from the first illuminae file thing, all in lowercase. there is no time, i have to leave this as vague as possible, but you can do this, you’ve gotten this far.
>
>  The "illuminae file" refers to [this series of books](http://amiekaufman.com/books/the-illuminae-files/illuminae/), so the name is likely Kady. The "public containment sector" might be the habitats mentioned [here](http://www.randomhouse.com/teens/illuminae/heimdall.php), so the password is either `habitatskady` or `habitatsKady`, with either the whole thing or just the name translated into binary.

Comment: Well done for solving this and the previous riddle! Also, close, but the sector name and kady grant are desperate, and you need to translate it into binary

Comment: @RohitJose I haven't translated it because there are a lot of options: what's capitalized? Is there a space? Do I use the first *and* last name? All of these change how it translates into binary, and the actual translation is just a mechanical step.

Comment: I see what you mean, but if you're interested, it was 'kady grant public containment' which would be 10010001 10100111 01110010 10000010 10110110 10100111 10110110 10011011 10011011 10010110 00100111 00011100 10100010 01111011 01011010 10001010 01111001 10011110 10011110 11010000